# SailsJs - Export html view to PDF

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, express, sails.js

I need to export a HTML view to a PDF.
I already have my view working and I want to create another link to generate a PDF version from this view.
I'm trying to use `http.get` to download the HTML file but it's not working.
Here's the code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.createWriteStream("files/" + filename);

var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + 'PATH/TO/MY/VIEW?id=' + id;

var request = http.get(fullUrl, function(response){
    response.pipe(file);    
});
```

The written file just outputs:

```
Found. Redirecting to /<default_pattern>
```

Comment: your scoping seems awkward, why is your `req.get` outside the callback? where is `filename` defined?

Comment: @Daniel_L this code is already inside a callback function. I didn't included because the part that giving me problems is the exposed.`req` is just the request object received in the sails controller function.   `filename` is just a string to name the created file.

Comment: Please try printing `fullUrl` then visit it via browser / curl. Does it return 2xx status code with expected file content? `curl --head <fullUrl>`. Does it return 301/302 by any chance?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of *downloading* you could use a html to pdf converter like [**wkhtmltopdf**](https://github.com/devongovett/node-wkhtmltopdf). Converting a view to pdf is simple as:

```
res.render('ticket/pdf', {
    'title': 'Ticket #1',
}, function(err, html) {
    if (err) {
        return res.negotiate(err);
    }
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=myFile.pdf';
    return require('wkhtmltopdf')(html).pipe(res);
});
```

The converter has to be installed on your system, refer to http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

If you still like to download a view, do the following:

```
wkhtmltopdf('http://google.com/', { pageSize: 'letter' })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.pdf'));
```

Comment: Nice, I'll try this approach